# Block direct downloads using Symfony

Tags: file, symfony, download

I want block the direct access to some of public files from my directory. For example, I have the file image.png and I have to fill a captcha to download that file, if I fail the captcha I don't want that the user could access the file. Is there any way to do that in Symfony?

Comment: I would really suggest to *move* these files outside of the public directory, and only serve them by passing a controller (see @Jeet's answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, create an `.htaccess` file inside the image directory to prevent the direct access of files inside the directory.

```
Deny from All
```

Now, give customised path, through `controller` to download the file, where you can easily integrate a `captcha` by using some bundle like [Gregwar's CaptchaBundle](https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle).

On successful captcha validation, download the file through `Response`.

```
$filename = __DIR__ . "../path_to_file/image.png";

// Generate response
$response = new Response();

// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'private');
$response->headers->set('Content-type', mime_content_type($filename));
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . basename($filename) . '";');
$response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($filename));

// Send headers before outputting anything
$response->sendHeaders();
$response->setContent(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Note : Code not tested!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think that it can works fine, but just one last question. I am using Nginx as server, I created the htaccess but it didn't work, I don't know if it is due to that Nginx server or another stuff

Comment: You have to change `Nginx` server config file for that. I don't have direct experience on setting up an `Nginx` server. You might like to follow these 2 links : [Conversion Tool](https://winginx.com/en/htaccess), [Config](http://serverfault.com/a/267510/401780)